# Monitor OpenVPN User Bandwidth Usage

Tags: linux, debian, openvpn

So i've been researching this as much as possible and i haven't found a specific result.

I'm trying to monitor the incoming and outgoing bandwidth of OpenVPN users, i'm removing as many logs as possible for security reasons on the server, so how can i still monitor and limit the bandwidth of a user without monitoring what they're doing, etc.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by not monitoring the users?

Comment: I want to limit the bandwidth that a user can use, other than that i need to keep everything that doesn't need to be there... removed

Answer (score 2):

I monitor and log the user bandwith storing the information from openvpn-status.log using the script below

https://github.com/jofrep/scripts/blob/master/openvpn/log-openvpn-users.pl

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Server Density plugin to monitor OpenVPN users and bandwidth. Bandwidth is global, and not per user basis:

https://github.com/bencer/sd-agent-plugins/blob/openvpn/OpenVPN/OpenVPN.py

Comment: So how would i intergrate this?